# Magento order grid: is it a new or an existing customer?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, orders, order-grid

```
Magento order grid: is it a new or an existing customer?
```

**Question:** Is there a way to mark or colour the order in the order grid based on the question: is it a new or an existing customer? - or how would I go about doing this

Preferably I would not only like to validate by account used - but rather by: has an order been placed before using the email address

Answer (score 0):

This could be done by joining with the same orders table and executing a count and group by.

The logic would be similar to

`SELECT * FROM CALLER WHERE USERNAME IN
  ( 
    SELECT USERNAME FROM CALLER
    GROUP BY USERNAME 
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1
  )`